# Adding drag and drop to a scroll area

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I'm trying to create a scroll area that will allow drag and drop in QtPy5. I want to be able to drag one label (label 1) to another label (Label 3) and have the label's switch places. (Ie 1, 2, 3, 4 ... becomes 3, 2, 1, 4 .....) So far I can get the scroll part working but I'm having trouble getting the drag and drop functional. I think the issue is I need to use setAcceptDrop(True) somewhere but I can't think where. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QScrollArea, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap

class DragItem(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setContentsMargins(25, 5, 25, 5)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;")
        # Store data separately from display label, but use label for default.
        self.data = self.text()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)

        
        
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.contents = QWidget()
        self.contents.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.contents)

               layout = QHBoxLayout(self.contents)

        for row in range(20):
            button = DragItem(str(row))
            layout.addWidget(button)
            
        def dropEvent(self, e):
            pos = e.pos()
            widget = e.source()
    
            for n in range(self.blayout.count()):
                # Get the widget at each index in turn.
                w = self.blayout.itemAt(n).widget()
                if pos.x() < w.x():
                    # We didn't drag past this widget.
                    # insert to the left of it.
                    self.blayout.insertWidget(n-1, widget)
                    break
    
            e.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: So if i am reading this right... you want to drag an image on top of the label and display the image?

Comment: Hi! I want to be able to drag one label (label 1) to another label (Label 3) and have the label's switch places. Ie 1, 2, 3, 4 ... becomes 3, 2, 1, 4 .....

Comment: Okay, now i see. is it okay to just move the widgets around or is it important that the widgets remain where they are and just the data gets transfered

Comment: Only the data needs to get transferred. The widgets themselves can stay put. Really what I'm curious about is why my current code isn't working. As in why it won't let me drag and drop anything.

Comment: Check out the first paragraph of my answer

Comment: I completely glossed over that the first time I saw it and went straight to the code. Thanks! I appreciate the help.

Comment: @NerdyMcnerdyFace you must really be more careful with your indentation. Right now, your code would cause a crash for that `layout = ...` line, and the `dropEvent` won't be called because it's at the same level as the `__init__` method. Indentation is an essential aspect of Python (and code styling in general), you shall *never* ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your current code is not allowing you to drop anything is because you have not implemented the `dragEnterEvent` and `dragMoveEvent`.  Both of them need to be accepted by the widget in order for them to accept drops.  Also the drop event you have in your `mainwindow` isn't actually doing anything because it is nested in your `__init__` function.

This is one way you could do it:

I created a signal on the main window with two parameters identifying the indices of the widgets you want to swap. When the signal is emitted it triggers a function to swap those widgets. Then I implemented `dragEnter` and `dragMove` events for each of the labels and adjusted the drop event to emit the `MainWindow` signal with the widgets positions in the layout.

I adjusted a few other things to make it more obvious what is happening when you run it.

```py
class DragItem(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.original = int(self.text())
        self.current = self.original
        self.setText(f"Original: {self.original}\n Current: {self.current}")
        self.setContentsMargins(25, 5, 25, 5)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;")
        # Store data separately from display label, but use label for default.
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def set_data(self, number):
        self.current = number
        self.setText(f"Original: {self.original}\n Current: {self.current}")

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasImage(): e.accept()
        else: e.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasImage(): e.accept()
        else: e.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        source_pos = e.source().current
        current_pos = self.current
        self.window().swap.emit(*sorted([source_pos, current_pos]))
        # or instead you can extract the pixmap from the event mime data
        # pixmap = e.mimeData().imageData()
        # ... do something with pixmap

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            mime.setImageData(pixmap)
            drag.setMimeData(mime)
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    swap = pyqtSignal([int,int])

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.contents = QWidget()
        self.contents.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.contents)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.contents)
        for row in range(20):
            button = DragItem(str(row))
            self.layout.addWidget(button)
        self.swap.connect(self.swap_widgets)

    def swap_widgets(self, pos1, pos2):
        widget1 = self.layout.itemAt(pos1).widget()
        widget2 = self.layout.itemAt(pos2).widget()
        self.layout.removeWidget(widget2)
        self.layout.removeWidget(widget1)
        self.layout.insertWidget(pos1, widget2)
        self.layout.insertWidget(pos2, widget1)
        widget1.set_data(pos2)
        widget2.set_data(pos1)
```

For more details on drag and drop in `qt` check out the official documentation.  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html

Comment: Note that the QMimeData *must* set a defined format and the possible receiver(s) should only accept the event as long as that format exists in the drag event mime data. With your current code, it's possible to drag objects from external sources, which will cause a crash in the `dropEvent()`. While that's expected, it's also expected that the program wouldn't crash for a possible involuntary drag from the user (for instance, if they were dragging from/to other sources and wrongly dropped the object on the application).

Comment: @musicamante  I added a link to the qt docs

Comment: That's a good addition, but it's better to clarify that aspect in your answer, as it's something that can **not** be ignored. Right now, your code can accept **any** drag event, no matter their source, which is wrong, since the result could cause involuntary crash. This is not a situation for which if something doesn't work as expected, it just doesn't work: a possible crash is a serious issue. The least you could (and should) do, is to add a custom mime format, a `hasFormat()` check in the `dragEnterEvent()`, and, also important, call the base implementation if the comparison isn't matched.

Comment: This is not something that could happen because the user makes something they are not expected to do with the program: it could happen even for a distraction; imagine the user trying to drag a file from the file manager to another program and accidentally releasing the mouse on *this* program in the process. It's like allowing the user to type 0 in a field used for a division and going on with the computation without a basic `try/except`. While we obviously cannot consider "user stupidity", the developer still *has* to be aware of these aspects.

Comment: @musicamante  okay

Comment: @Alexander Your response was very helpful, thank you for your time spent.